# Removing all layers form leaflet map every 24 hours

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I want my map to remove all layers every 24hours.

This code works but only removes the most recent layer posted.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    map.removeLayer(marker)
}, 2000).addto(map)
```

Ive tried using `markers.clearLayers` but it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [eachLayer](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-eachlayer) method to loop through all of the layer of your map and remove those.

```js
map.eachLayer(layer => {
    map.removeLayer(layer)
})
```